# Angular HostBinding testing for css class

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a wrapper with a loading, an error display and the actual content. Depending on some inputs I want to show one or another.

I want to test if given any error a 'centered__holder' class is added

The component:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'sd-ui-state-wrapper',
  templateUrl: './ui-state-wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ui-state-wrapper.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class UIStateWrapperComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() isLoading: boolean;
  @Input() errors: string[] | undefined;
  @HostBinding('class.centered__holder') centeredCss: boolean = false;

  [...]

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.centeredCss = this.isLoading || this.errors !== undefined && this.errors.length > 0;
  }
}
```

The test:

```ts
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [UIStateWrapperComponent],
  })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UIStateWrapperComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.errors = errorMock;
  fixture.detectChanges();
}));

it('should add centered__holder class', async (done) => {
  component.ngOnChanges();
  fixture.whenStable()
    .then(() => {
      console.log(fixture.debugElement.classes.centered__holder);
      console.log(component.centeredCss);

      expect(fixture.debugElement.classes.centered__holder)
        .toBeTruthy();
      done();
    });
});
```

But the console shows: true, false
I've also tried with `fixture.whenRenderingDone()`

How can I wait for HostBinding class to be applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixture.nativeElement.classList.contains('centered__holder') should be what you are looking for. There's more on the fixture as well for other bound properties.